# Struts2 param within result not working

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action, param

It seems I should be able to have parameters in strut.xml defined PER result, and not globally, but I cannot get it to work. Here is what does work :

```xml
<action name="actThing" class="Thing" method="execute">
    <interceptor-ref name="newStack" />
    <param name="parentObject">Parent</param>
    <result name="Edit">jspEditThing.jsp</result>
    <result name="Add">jspAddThing.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In this case when Thing.execute gets called, the `parentObject` variable is set. But here :

```xml
<action name="actThing" class="Thing" method="execute">
    <interceptor-ref name="newStack" />
    <result name="Add">
        <param name="location">jspAddThing.jsp</param>
        <param name="parentObject">Parent</param>
    </result>
    <result name="Edit">jspEditThing.jsp</result>
</action>
```

it does not. Since it works in the first case I certainly have the proper settings/getters, and I don't get any kind of error. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, and it shouldn't because parameters are applied to the result, not the action. The result is executed after the action, and all parameters should be already set.

> The param tag sets a property on the `Result` object. The most commonly-set property is `location`, which usually specifies the path to a web resources. The `param` attribute is another intelligent default.

Answer (score 0):

```
<action name="actThing" class="Thing" method="execute">
            <result name="Add">
                <param name="includeProperties">Parent.*</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Now your Parent object with all its attributes and child objects will be available.